# horizontal adjustment of side caption after tikz arrow addition

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tikz-arrows, floatrow

I have a figure with side caption and I added an arrow to the image but now everything is not centered anymore since I added the arrow, is there a way to force the centering to accommodate the added arrow I made using tikz? Thanks for your time.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (0,0);
    \node[single arrow,draw=black,fill=black,minimum height=4.8cm, rotate=270] at (3.8,-2.8) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption here}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.32]{SizeExChrom}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that the widht of the arrow is discarded since you used `\useasboundingbox (0,0);`

To have a better control over the arrow positioning, I'd suggest you to include also the image inside a `\node` in the `tikzpicture` and keep the natural bounding box, so the proper width will be taken into account for the centering. An additional advantage is that now, with the help of the `calc` library, you can let TikZ calculate the height for the arrow:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption here}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] (image)
  {\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=7cm]{example-image-a}};
\path
  let
  \p1=(image.north),
  \p2=(image.south)
  in
  node[
    single arrow,
    draw=black,
    fill=black,
    minimum height=\y1-\y2,
    rotate=270
    ] 
    at ([shift={(20pt,0pt)}]image.east) {};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, don't use `[!h]` as float placement specifier since it's so restrictive that is a recipe for disaster; either use a less restrictive specifier or none at all.

Comment: great, thanks for the help/advice. im quite new to latex. if you would please explain what \path let is? i tried looking it up and they only discuss about filling, drawing, shading, etc for lines. also, what are the variables \p1-2 and \y1-2? thanks again.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh You're welcome. Regarding the let syntax, you can find it in section **14.15 The Let Operation** of the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). It allows to make assignments to resiters that can then be used in calculations, placement etc. `\p<number>` stores the two coordinates of a point which can then be accessed as `\x<number>` (the x-ccordinate) and `\y<number>` (the y-ccordinate). In my example `\p1` has the coordinates of the north anchor of the node with the image and `\p2` has the coordinates of the south anchor.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh  Then you can use the y-coordinates `\y1` and `\y2` to compute the height: `\y1-\y2` and use it as minimum height for the arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were trying to achieve (more or less)?

[image: floatbox]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,showframe,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={left,top},capbesidewidth=4cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption{caption here}}%
{\includegraphics[height=4.8cm]{example-image}\begin{tikzpicture}
%\useasboundingbox (0,0);
    \node[single arrow,draw=black,fill=black,minimum height=4.8cm, rotate=270] at (3.8,-2.8) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```